# Kubernetes cluster name change

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I'm creating a cluster with `kubeadm init --with-stuff` (Kubernetes 1.8.4, for reasons). I can setup nodes, `weave`, etc. But I have a problem setting the cluster name. When I open the `admin.conf` or a different config file I see:

```
name: kubernetes
```

When I run `kubectl config get-clusters`:

```
NAME
kubernetes
```

Which is the default. Is there a way to set the cluster name during `init` (there is no command line parameter)? Or is there a way to change this after the `init`? The current `name` is referenced in many files in `/etc/kubernetes/`

Best Regrads
Kamil

Answer (score 5):

You can now do so using kubeadm's config file. PR here:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/60852

Using the kubeadm config you just set the following at the top level

```
clusterName: kubernetes
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot change a name of running cluster, because it serves for discovery inside a cluster and this would require near-simultaneous changing it across the cluster.

Sadly, you also cannot change a name of the cluster before `init`. Here is the issue on [Github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/416).

**Update:** From version 1.12, `kubeadm` allow you to change a cluster name before an "init" stage.

To do it (for sure for versions >=1.15, for lower versions commands can be different, commands changed somewhen between versions 1.12 and 1.15), you need to set `clusterName` value in a cluster configuration file like that:

1. Save default configuration to a file (cluster config is optional, so we need to do that step first for not to write it from scratch) by a `kubeadm config print init-defaults < init-config.yaml` command.
2. Set  `clusterName` value in the config.
3. Run `kubeadm` init with a config argument: `kubeadm init --config init-config.yaml`

Comment: That's a bit of a disaster if you want to change the name of a running cluster then!